# Approximating the Indicator Function Using Continuous Functions

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

How do you approximate the indicator function $1_{A}(x)$ (which equals 1 if $x\in A$, 0 if $x$ not $\in A$ using continuous functions?

Comment: It depends on how you characterize 'approximate'.

Comment: Convolution with a mollifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I realized I was assuming that you want to approximate a simple function $\Sigma c_i \chi_{E_i}$ by a continuous function  $f$, tho that may not be the case. Still, if you want to to do this,
The method I know is by joining the right- and left- endpoints of $c_i \chi_ {E_i}$ by line segments between $ \chi_{E_i}$ and $\chi_{E_{i+i}}$ and with $\chi_{E_{i-1}}$. Then you join the constant function $c_i$ in $E_i$ to the constant value $c_{i-1}$

Comment: What do you mean by an endpoint?

Comment: I mean the $c_i\chi_{E_i}$ are line segments, since the function takes constant value $c_i$ in $E_i$ ( I forgot to include the$c_i$ in the original; let me edit. )

Comment: @copper.hat : Sorry, I realized I was trying to approximate a characteristic function by a continuous function, tho that is not what the OP may have intended.

Comment: I am still not sure what the OP was looking for :-).

Comment: And I still answer questions that are only on my mind. Serenity Now!!!! :) .

Comment: This only works if the $E_i$ are compact. What if $E_1 = \mathbb{Q}$ and $E_2 = \mathbb{Q}^c$?

Comment: Then you have a uniformly continuous function defined on a dense subset and it extends uniquely to a globally-continuous function.

Comment: @user170431 But then can't the approximation be arbitrarily bad? Say we define the function on $\mathbb{Q}$, then the unique extension disagrees with $\sum c_i \chi_i$ except on a set of measure zero.

Comment: @orizon :Yes, you do give up some good qualities, but only on a set of measure zero

Comment: @orizon: Problem is OP did not specify the conditions s/he wanted the approximation to satisfy.